# How to delete from table A and table B (if exists) in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried this below without success, it just fails because table_B is empty. So I want to at least delete the record from table_A even if table_B is empty.

FYI: table_A record always exists, so no need to search if that exists.

```
$sql_remove_rfid = $dbi->prepare("
DELETE 
  FROM table_A
     , table_B
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_B 
    ON table_A.id = table_B.key
WHERE table_A.id=?");
```

Comment: A LEFT JOIN on a DELETE is a decidedly odd thing. Descartes would be baffled.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is not quite correct, it should be:

```
DELETE A, B
FROM table_A A
LEFT JOIN table_B B ON A.id = B.key
WHERE A.id=?
```

Note that in general its best to avoid using MySQL reserved words (`key`) as column names.

Note also that if `key` is a foreign key from `table_B` to `table_A`, and you always want to delete entries from `table_B` when the corresponding `id` in `table_A` is deleted, you can define `key` as a foreign key to `table_A(id)` and specify `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_B ADD FOREIGN KEY (`key`) REFERENCES table_A(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Then you can simply delete from `table_A` and the corresponding rows in `table_B` (if any) will automatically be deleted:

```
DELETE
FROM table_A
WHERE id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you wish to delete data from TABLEA against an id regardless of whether the id exists in TABLEB. Therefore why the JOIN condition. It can be

```
$sql_remove_rfid = $dbi->prepare("DELETE FROM 
table_A
WHERE table_A.id=?");
```

Comment: What about table_B?

Comment: Do you want to delete from table_B ALL the those records which exist in table_A